# D3 change Dataset csv

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I have a question about 'D3.js'. I want a dropdown where different datasets can be selected. Can anyone help me. I have created a Plunker.

[Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/KxsUAztnD39HNXRzUF87?p=preview)

CSV-Format:

```
Country, Men, Women
GB, 10.1,20
FR, 20.8,5.2
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make the drawing of the chart a function so it can be called at will.

```
var draw = function(data_source) {...
```

Call the function on a change of the drop-down.

```
<select name="data" onchange="change(this.value)">
```

Clear the SVG and draw a new chart.

```
function change(value) {
  svg.selectAll("*").remove();
  draw(value);
}
```

[Plunk](http://plnkr.co/edit/XsACvHTxFfBho8XYLnna?p=preview)

Comment: Thanks. I just thought too complicated. Have a nice day :)